Importing PDF into Word using Powershell
I'm running the below code to convert large PDF-files into Word and execute them via Powershell, but keep running into the below error. I've cast the confirmConversions/link/attachment parameters to a an object explicitly, but that doesn't help.
# Define paths
$folderPath = "my source folder"
$resultPath = "my destination folder"

# Create Word application COM object
$wordApp = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wordApp.Visible = $false  # Set Word to run in the background

# Create FileSystemObject COM object
$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

# Get the folder
$folder = $fso.GetFolder($folderPath)

# Loop through each file in the folder
foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
    # Create a new Word document
    $newDoc = $wordApp.Documents.Add()

    # Explicitly cast the boolean and object parameters as [ref] objects for the InsertFile method
    $confirmConversions = [ref] $false
    $link = [ref] $false
    $attachment = [ref] $false

    # Insert the content of the current file into the new document
    $newDoc.Range().InsertFile($file.Path, [ref] $null, $confirmConversions, $link, $attachment)

    # Optionally, add some additional text or actions to the new document
    $newDoc.Content.InsertBefore("Processed document: " + $file.Name + "`n")

    # Define the document name and save it
    $docName = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($resultPath, ($file.Name -replace ".\w+$", "_processed.docx"))
    $newDoc.SaveAs([ref] $docName, [ref] 16)  # 16 = wdFormatXMLDocument for .docx

    # Close the document after saving
    $newDoc.Close([ref] $false)
}

# Cleanup
$wordApp.Quit()
$fso = $null
[System.GC]::Collect()  # Force garbage collection to release COM objects

Error:
Exception setting "InsertFile": Cannot convert the "False" value of type "bool" to type "Object".
At [my source folder]#ProcessWordDocs.ps1:26 char:5
+     $newDoc.Range().InsertFile($file.Path, [ref] $null, $confirmConve ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Try [Type]::Missing instead of [ref]$false

Then I get Exception setting "InsertFile": Cannot convert the System.Reflection.Missing" value of type "Missing" to type "Object".

Because all parameters for InsertFile() are optional (except the first one of course), you could also try leaving them out all together, since you define them all as $false. By the way, Why do you use the Scripting.FileSystemObject com object to enumerate the files in the source folder instead of the Get-ChildItem cmdlet?

I've tried leaving them out all together, but that resulted in another error. I've found a different approach that doesn't involve Powershell though

Here's a way of doing this without using the InsertFile() method.
You can simply open the pdf with word to have it converted into a document, so all you need to do after that is to save the document to a different path with a new extension:
# Define paths
$folderPath = "my source folder"
$resultPath = "my destination folder"  # make sure the path exists

# Create Word application COM object
$wordApp = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wordApp.Visible = $false  # Set Word to run in the background

# Loop through each file in the folder
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter '*.pdf' -File)) {
    # Create a new Word document
    $newDoc = $wordApp.Documents.Open($file.FullName)

    # Optionally, add some additional text or actions to the new document
    $newDoc.Content.InsertBefore("Processed document: " + $file.Name + "`r`n")

    # Combine the document new path and name and save it
    $docName = Join-Path -Path $resultPath -ChildPath ('{0}_processed.docx' -f $file.BaseName)
    $wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("$docName", 16)   # 16 = wdFormatXMLDocument for .docx
    # Close the document after saving
    $newDoc.Close()
}

# quit Word and cleanup the used COM objects
$wordApp.Quit()

$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($newDoc)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wordApp)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()


That works perfectly, thank you!
